# Как заставить background-size: cover; работать на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: css, css3

Как заставить background-size: cover; работать на мобильных устройствах?

```
.firstsection{
    background-image: url(../wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Header_Background.jpg);
    background-image: -webkit-image-set(url(../wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Header_Background.webp)1x );
    background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Добавил сам код в вопрос

Comment: Во-первых, background:cover и background-size:cover это разные вещи. Во-вторых, почему вы решили, что это не работает на мобильных устройствах?

Comment: Исправил, потому что картинка не заполняет див

Comment: На моих мобильных устройствах заполняет. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @andreymal таки не на всех работает - потому через js решаю. Ну, наверное это только у меня так глючит, не буду утверждать, но факт есть факт. Имеется background на весь body - подложка.

Comment: @Coder да, на Nokia 3310 действительно не работает

Comment: @andreymal На iphone 7 + не работает ни на штатном браузере, ни на crome. Да что спорить? - Ну, если у Вас все хорошо, то и хорошо. А у меня так, потому и так делается.

Comment: @Coder у меня на iphone 5 работало, так что вынужден подвергнуть данное высказывание сомнению (ну и не забываем, что chrome это просто обёртка для штатного браузера)

Comment: @andreymal Ну, я же не для просто покататься тут выступить решил - в общем, кому что и как - просто имхо - меня не устраивает, что где-то может что не так, потому через js - везде так. Ну, вот как-то так - дале спорить не стоит, думаю.